# jQuery append duplicating on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append some information that is in a loop and I'm getting the right results on console.log but after appending it, each result is appended several times

MY CODE:

```
let success = function(res) {
        let coinsRedemption = res['coinsRedempt']
        let rewardsRedemption = res['rewardsRedempt']

for(i=0; i<coinsRedemption.length;i++){
    let coinType = coinsRedemption[i]['coin_type']
    let coinTime = coinsRedemption[i]['visit_date']
    let firstName = coinsRedemption[i]['first_name']

    for(j=0; j<rewardsRedemption.length; j++){
        let rewardName = rewardsRedemption[i]['reward_name']
        let rewardDateClaimed = rewardsRedemption[i]['date_claimed']
        let rewardCompleteDate = rewardsRedemption[i]['complete_date']
        let firstName1 = rewardsRedemption[i]['first_name']

        $('#redeemptionsTable tbody').append(`
        <tr class='redempTableRows'>
            <td class='coin-redemption'>${coinType}</td>
            <td class='coin-redemption-time'>${coinTime}</td>
            <td class='coin-redemption-location'> ${firstName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='rewardRedempTableRows'>
            <td class='reward-redemption'>${rewardName}</td>
            <td class='reward-redemption-time'>${rewardDateClaimed}</td>
            <td class='reward-redemption-location'>${firstName1}</td>
        </tr> `)
    }
```

THE RESULTS

[image]

How can I avoid make it append the results only once?

PS: I have looked into questions answering the same thing but they haven't helped me.

Comment: Can you show the `coinsRedemption` var as well?

Comment: Yes, I added it, the information is coming from the database.

Comment: how long is `coinsRedemption.length` and how many times is it appending the repeating values? it seems like you're getting repeating values because the second loop is running all the way through, then its going back to the outer for loop and running the inner for loop again for every iteration of the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

The `redempTableRows` row should be output in the outer loop, not the inner loop.

```js
let success = function(res) {
  let coinsRedemption = res['coinsRedempt']
  let rewardsRedemption = res['rewardsRedempt']

  for (i = 0; i < coinsRedemption.length; i++) {
    let coinType = coinsRedemption[i]['coin_type']
    let coinTime = coinsRedemption[i]['visit_date']
    let firstName = coinsRedemption[i]['first_name']
    $("#redemptionsTable tbody").append(`
      <tr class='redempTableRows'>
          <td class='coin-redemption'>${coinType}</td>
          <td class='coin-redemption-time'>${coinTime}</td>
          <td class='coin-redemption-location'> ${firstName}</td>
      </tr>`);
    for (j = 0; j < rewardsRedemption.length; j++) {
      let rewardName = rewardsRedemption[i]['reward_name']
      let rewardDateClaimed = rewardsRedemption[i]['date_claimed']
      let rewardCompleteDate = rewardsRedemption[i]['complete_date']
      let firstName1 = rewardsRedemption[i]['first_name']

      $('#redeemptionsTable tbody').append(`
        <tr class='rewardRedempTableRows'>
            <td class='reward-redemption'>${rewardName}</td>
            <td class='reward-redemption-time'>${rewardDateClaimed}</td>
            <td class='reward-redemption-location'>${firstName1}</td>
        </tr> `)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only removed the 'coinsRedemption' from the table and all of the 'redeemptionsTable' are still duplicated :/

Comment: Why are you doing that as a nested loop? You're repeating the same array for each coinsRedemption. How are the two arrays related?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the two arrays and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: I put them together because 'coinsRedemption' is coming from a table (database) and 'redeemptionsTable' is coming from another table (database); what I want is for both results to be mixed on the same <table> which would be (#redeemptionsTable). I have tried separate them but if I don't do inner loops then it only display results from one table (ex: just 'coinsRedemption' and ignores the other loop for 'redeemptionsTable') but if I do inner loops and append I get what I want but with duplicated results.

Comment: Please show some sample data and how you want the table to look.